# Find the last record in previous month to compare with in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Bit of a strange one. Assume I have a database table in a rails 4 app like this.

[data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJQVt.png)

And this table is represented by a model, being `Metric`. You can see that the last metric for the previous month had a value for `total_users` of 100, and the most recent value for `total_users` is 105.

What I need to be able to do is compare the most recent value of `total_users` with the last one for the previous month and come up with the difference. So if we call this variable `@net_addition`, at the moment the value should be '5', being the difference between 100 and 105.

Obviously the latest record is easy, being `Metric.order("created_at").last`.

Where I am having a brain block is in finding the last record for the previous month. I'm thinking I need to group the data by month somehow, then find the most recent(but not the current) group, and within that find the last record?

the other thing I thought about was maybe looking to see if the current record is in a different month than the last record and somehow marking that record as being the one for comparison if so, so the last record in each month would end up with a flag against it?

Can anyone get me started?

Comment: Its not really clear what you mean by "if the current record is in a different month than the last record..." - what does the current record mean in this context? What is the desired result? Do you want the records grouped by month?

Answer (score 1):

You can scope by date range

```
start_date = 1.month.ago.beginning_of_month
end_date = 1.month.ago.end_of_month

Metric.where(created_at: start_date..end_date)
      .order(created_at: :desc).first
```

Answer (score 1):

```
last_month = Time.current - 1.month
Metric.order("created_at").where(
  created_at: last_month.beginning_of_month..last_month.end_of_month
).last
```

Using [a range](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Range.html) creates a `WHERE created_at BETWEEN a AND b` clause.

Comment: You can also do this by extracting the year and month using the date functions in the database which is handy if you need to use it in a group clause. Unfortunatly they are not that standardized and you need a db specific solution.